# Getting all nodes in a BeanTreeView

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I have a BeanTreeView that shows a some nodes. And I have another component that isn't netbeans-related that needs to know what is in the tree at this moment. Preferably just a straight list of the nodes in the tree. (Clarification; when I talk about nodes here I mean netbeans nodes, not the TreeNodes in a JTree.)

I haven't found any useful methods of doing this. I can't seem to get the information from the associated ExplorerManager that's connected to the BeanTreeView. So far I've subclassed the BeanTreeView and added the private method

```
private List<Object> getNodesAsList(){
    LinkedList<Object> result = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
        TreePath pathForRow = tree.getPathForRow(i);
        Object lastPathComponent = pathForRow.getLastPathComponent();
        result.add(lastPathComponent);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The Object I get from getLastPathComponent is a VisualizerNode, which holds the node I want to get. But I can't cast to VisualizerNode since it's not public in org.openide.explorer.view. And it's final. And there's no getters for the node anyway...

Any ideas? I feel like there's something I've missed with the ExplorerManager...

Update; this worked for me, could probably be done more elegant. Thanks paddy!

```
private List<Node> getNodesInTree(){
    LinkedList<Node> result = new LinkedList<>();
    ExplorerManager em = ExplorerManager.find(this);
    for (Node node : em.getRootContext().getChildren().getNodes()) {
        result.add(node);
        result.addAll(getChildNodesInTree(node));
    }
    return result;
}

private List<Node> getChildNodesInTree(Node root){
    LinkedList<Node> result = new LinkedList<>();
    if(root.getChildren().getNodesCount() > 0){
        if(isExpanded(root)){
            for (Node node : root.getChildren().getNodes()) {
                result.add(node);
                result.addAll(getChildNodesInTree(node));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`ExplorerManager.getRootContext()`](http://bits.netbeans.org/7.3.1/javadoc/org-openide-explorer/org/openide/explorer/ExplorerManager.html#getRootContext%28%29). This returns the root Node shown in your ExplorerManager. From this node you could iterate through all the other nodes (using [`Node.getChildren()`](http://bits.netbeans.org/7.3.1/javadoc/org-openide-nodes/org/openide/nodes/Node.html#getChildren%28%29)) and create your own list. I am not aware of a function that handles that for you.

Comment: Yes I've tried that, the problem is that with Node.getChildren() I get all possible children, I'm interested in only the ones that are visible in the BeanTreeView.. :/ So if I do getChildren() on a node that isn't expanded in the view, I get the children it would have if it were expanded.

Comment: BeanTreeView offers a method [`isExpanded(Node node)`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-explorer/org/openide/explorer/view/TreeView.html#isExpanded(org.openide.nodes.Node)). You could use this to filter out the nodes, that you don't want to use.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! I tried using isExpanded before, but then I did it on all nodes including the leafs... I should check if it has any children at all before isExpanded of course.